# Can't access the class variables from a event handler

Tags: javascript, class, event-handling, private-methods

I am making a web application for arranging seats, and I have written these codes:

```
class SeatMap {
    constructor (parentElement) {
        this.#createSeats();
    }

    #createSeats () {
        this.seatList = [];
        for (let a = 0; a < this.row; a++) {
            for (let b = 0; b < this.column; b++) {
                this.seatList[a].push(new Seat(this,a,b));
            }
        }
    }

class Seat {
    constructor(seatContainer, rowNum, colNum) {
        this.seatContainer = seatContainer;
        this.seatTB.addEventListener("keydown", this.#keydownTB);
    }

    // Key Events Handler
    #keydownTB (event) {
        const seatContainerConector = this.seatContainer;
        if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
            console.log(seatContainerConector); // Undefined
        }
    }
}

// I only wrote codes related to the problem here.
```

However, `console.log(seatContainerConector);` just gives me back  `undefined`.
I have tried to delete `const seatContainerConector = this.seatContainer;` and use `console.log(this.seatContainer);` instead, but it didn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post where `<Seat>` is consumed/rendered? If this is from the API, you'd expect it to be undefined until the request comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hard to debug since you leave out some essential elements, like   `new SeatMap()`, `row` and `column`, `this.seatTB`, etc.

One problem in your keydown event handler is that your scope is not what you expect.  That causes `this.seatContainer` to refer to the wrong scope. Instead of the class instance you refer to the element that caused the keydown event. On that element, `this.seatContainer` is `undefined`

You can fix that with the arrow function.

```
this.seatTB.addEventListener("click",  (e) => this.keydownTB(e));
```

Now `this` will refer to the instance of `new Seat()` instead of the element that caused the event.